# Show that Newton Method convergence cannot be greater than 2

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

> How can I show that the convergence of of Newton's method can't be of order $k$ where $k > 2$?

I have that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^{n+1}-\alpha}{(x^n-\alpha)^2}=\frac{f''(\alpha)}{2f'(\alpha)}.$$

And that
$$f''(\alpha) \neq 0$$

I know that I need to show that there doesn't exist a constant $C > 0$ such that $|x^{n+1}-\alpha| \leq C|x^n-\alpha|^k$ for $k>2$.

Could anyone give me some pointers on how I could show this?

Comment: Actually, it's doable for certain $f$. Big-$O$ notation will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|x^{n+1}-\alpha| \le C|x^n - \alpha|^k$ where $k > 2$, then
$$\frac{x^{n+1} - \alpha}{(x^n - \alpha)^2} \to 0,$$
which contradicts $f''(\alpha) \ne 0$.